# Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line

Tags: errors, conditionals

On the question [Is it possible to keep my translation together with original text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5076/is-it-possible-to-keep-my-translation-together-with-original-text) I learned how to do an if, however when I use it like on this document:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugfalse
\debugtrue

\begin{document}

Arquivo compilado \ifdebug22:00\else\currenttime\fi h do dia \ifdebugTODAY\else\today\if.

\end{document}
```

It throws the error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.81 ...else\currenttime\fi h do dia \ifdebugTODAY
                                                  \else\today\if.
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Extra \else.
l.81 ...currenttime\fi h do dia \ifdebugTODAY\else
                                                  \today\if.
I'm ignoring this; it doesn't match any \if.

)
! Incomplete \if; all text was ignored after line 81.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ./test2.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test2.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

But if I change the if line adding some spaces:

```
Arquivo \ifdebug 22:00 \else \currenttime \fi h do dia \ifdebug TODAY \else \today \if .
```

The error became:

```
! Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line 81.
<inserted text> 
                \fi 
<*> ./test2.tex

The file ended while I was skipping conditional text.
This kind of error happens when you say `\if...' and forget
the matching `\fi'. I've inserted a `\fi'; this might work.

! Emergency stop.
<*> ./test2.tex

*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)
```

---

Related:

1. [Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 1499](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/330475/incomplete-iffalse-all-text-was-ignored-after-line-1499)
2. [! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 22. In \IEEEauthorblockN](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164341/incomplete-iffalse-all-text-was-ignored-after-line-22-in-ieeeauthorblockn)
3. ["Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line x" with lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/376763/incomplete-iffalse-all-text-was-ignored-after-line-x-with-lstlisting)
4. [incomplete \ifodd , all text was ignored... error](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236692/incomplete-ifodd-all-text-was-ignored-error)

Comment: (general guideline: [errors - How to diagnose unclosed (incomplete) \iftrue or \ifnum? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/285149/250119) // more questions with same error message: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/510798) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508985) [3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/179542) [4](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/472512))

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two errors from typos:

```
Arquivo compilado \ifdebug22:00\else\currenttime\fi h do dia \ifdebugTODAY\else\today\if.
```

The first error is `\ifdebugTODAY`, which refers to an unknown `\debugTODAY` conditional, so the space between `\ifdebug` and `TODAY` matters here.

The space is not necessary for `\ifdebug22:00` since the digits after `\ifdebug` clearly delimit the name of the `debug` conditional.

The second error is the `\if` at the end. It should read `\fi`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe,pass]{geometry}

\newif\ifdebug
\debugfalse
\debugtrue

\begin{document}

Arquivo compilado \ifdebug 22:00\else\currenttime\fi h do dia \ifdebug TODAY\else\today\fi.

\end{document}
```