# Why do I get an "Incomplete \ifx" in this MWE?

Tags: conditionals

I am trying to redefine the figure environment, which works fine in general. However, if the body of the figure environment to be replaced includes a `tabular` environment inside a conditional expression, I receive the error

> "Incomplete \ifx; all text was ignored after line 11"

I find this pretty surprising, since my renewed environment does not even used that body. It does not strictly depend on `tabular`, a `tikzpicture` raises the same error. Also, it does not depend on `\ifpdf`, other valid conditionals raise the same error, too.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\RenewEnviron{figure}{It's gone!}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\ifpdf
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        This works without RenewEnviron, ifpdf or tabular!
    \end{tabular}
\else\fi
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting: it seems to work if you enclose the `tabular` in a group.

Comment: `\usepackage{newenviron}` and `\renewenviron{figure}{It's gone!}` fixes the issue, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At one point the package fails to protect its internal conditional testing from stray `if..` tokens in the source. As it has scanned as far as the nested `\begin` it has scanned over the `\ifpdf` but not yet seen the matching `\fi`.  A small redefinition moves the collected tokens out of the internal `\ifx` test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\long\def\Collect@@Body#1\end#2{%
  \edef\begin@stack{%
    \Push@Begins#1\begin\end\expandafter\@gobble\begin@stack}%
  \ifx\@empty\begin@stack
    \endgroup
    \@checkend{#2}%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \fi
   {\Addto@Envbody{#1}}%
   {\Addto@Envbody{#1\end{#2}}}%
  \process@envbody}
\makeatother

\RenewEnviron{figure}{It's gone!}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\ifpdf
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        This works without RenewEnviron, ifpdf or tabular!
    \end{tabular}
\else\fi
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: reported as https://github.com/wspr/will2e/issues/8

Answer (score 2):

The `environ` package might be considered obsolete, now that the LaTeX kernel allows `\NewDocumentEnvironment` and `\RenewDocumentEnvironment` to take an argument specifier `b` (standing for “body”).

The syntax is a bit different

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{figure}
  {+b}% argument specifiers
  {It's gone!}% begin part
  {}% end part

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\ifpdf
    \begin{tabular}{l}
        This works without RenewEnviron, ifpdf or tabular!
    \end{tabular}
\else\fi
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

because the “end part” has to be specified (differently from `environ`). The `+` prefix means that empty lines are allowed in the environment.

Comment: Don't need `ifpdf` either, if you really want to cut it down ;)